# How to pass params with history.push/Link/Redirect in react-router v4?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

How can we pass parameter with `this.props.history.push('/page')` in React-Router v4?

```
.then(response => {
       var r = this;
        if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
             r.props.history.push('/template');
          });
```

Comment: The component that is rendered by a `Route` should have access to `this.props.location`, `this.props.history`, etc. I think you don't need to use `ref` anymore with v4. Try doing `this.props.history.push('/template');`

Comment: It is not ref ,It is variable that pointing to this; this.props.history.push('/template');  take me to next page but i want to pass props with them .ref = this;

Comment: You're trying to pass `props` to the component that matches the route? I think [this GitHub thread](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4105) addresses your concern.

Comment: JFYI - I have removed <a href> and added <Link> which also has option to send state, which can be accessed by next page via, this.props.location.state.

Comment: Could you please mark one of the replies as 'answer'. I am sure the people who spend time typing them will appreciate it.

Answer (score 562):

First of all, you need not do `var r = this;` as this in `if statement` refers to the context of the callback itself which since you are using arrow function refers to the React component context.

### According to the docs:

> history objects typically have the following properties and methods:
>
> - length - (number) The number of entries in the history stack
> - action - (string) The current action (PUSH, REPLACE, or POP)
> - location - (object) The current location. May have the following    properties:
>
>   - pathname - (string) The path of the URL
>   - search - (string) The URL query string
>   - hash - (string) The URL hash fragment
>   - state - (string) location-specific state that was provided to e.g.    push(path, state) when this location was pushed onto the
>       stack. Only     available in browser and memory history.
> - push(path, [state]) - (function) Pushes a new entry onto the history    stack
> - replace(path, [state]) - (function) Replaces the current entry on the    history stack
> - go(n) - (function) Moves the pointer in the history stack by n    entries
> - goBack() - (function) Equivalent to go(-1)
> - goForward() - (function) Equivalent to go(1)
> - block(prompt) - (function) Prevents navigation

So while navigating you can pass props to the history object like

```
this.props.history.push({
  pathname: '/template',
  search: '?query=abc',
  state: { detail: response.data }
})
```

or similarly for the `Link` component or the `Redirect` component

```
<Link to={{
      pathname: '/template',
      search: '?query=abc',
      state: { detail: response.data }
    }}> My Link </Link>
```

and then in the component which is rendered with `/template` route, you can access the props passed like

```
this.props.location.state.detail
```

Also keep in mind that, when using history or location objects from props you need to connect the component with `withRouter`.

### As per the Docs:

> **withRouter**
>
> You can get access to the history object’s properties and the closest
>   `<Route>'s` match via the `withRouter` higher-order component. `withRouter`
>   will re-render its component every time the route changes with the
>   same props as `<Route>` render `props: { match, location, history }`.

Comment: yes, that worked.Thanks!  But not sure why `this.props.history.push('/template',response.data)` not working. 

According to docs of `push(path, [state])`, don't you think it should work?

Comment: Thanks for this! In my case I was only passing history directly, so I accessed my prop via this.props.history.location.state.propName -

Comment: @SanketPatel you need to do this this.props.history.push('/template', {response: response.data})

Comment: Is it possible to open the route in a new tab while passing data in the state variable when navigating you can pass props to the history object?

Comment: what about goBack() ? when navigating back with goBack(), I cannot see any of the history states in either props.location or props.history.location.

Navigating forwards with push() it works fine

Comment: In "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2" putting 'state' inside the object causes error.
we can put any valid name like 'data' instead of 'state'. 
So it will be like, 
<Link to={{
      pathname: '/template',
      search: '?query=abc',
      data: { detail: response.data }
    }}> My Link </Link>

Comment: After refreshing the page, state values were getting lost. Any solution for that?

Comment: @MariusB only `push` and `replace` support a state object.

Comment: Tip of the day ⚠ - react - redux - react-router-dom: If you are watching location in some useEffect function, don't forget to resend your "queryParams" to avoid refreshing state lol

Answer (score 178):

**Extending the solution (suggested by Shubham Khatri) for use with React hooks (16.8 onwards):**

```
package.json (always worth updating to latest packages)

{
     ...

     "react": "^16.12.0",
     "react-router-dom": "^5.1.2",

     ...
}
```

**Passing parameters with history push:**

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";

const FirstPage = props => {
    let history = useHistory();

    const someEventHandler = event => {
       history.push({
           pathname: '/secondpage',
           search: '?query=abc',
           state: { detail: 'some_value' }
       });
    };

};

export default FirstPage;
```

**Accessing the passed parameter using useLocation from 'react-router-dom':**

```
import { useEffect } from "react";
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const SecondPage = props => {
    const location = useLocation();

    useEffect(() => {
       console.log(location.pathname); // result: '/secondpage'
       console.log(location.search); // result: '?query=abc'
       console.log(location.state.detail); // result: 'some_value'
    }, [location]);

};
```

Comment: Thank you so much, couldn't find an updated alternative except your answer!

Comment: Perfect!! Just perfect!!.
Precisely what I've been looking for.

Answer (score 102):

1. For the **earlier** versions:

   ```js
   history.push('/[pathToSomeWhere]', yourData);
   ```

   And get the data in the related component just like below:

   ```js
   this.props.location.state // it is equal to yourData
   ```
2. For the **newer** versions *the above way works well* but there is a new way:

   ```js
   history.push({
     pathname: '/[pathToSomeWhere]',
     state: yourData,
   });
   ```

   And get the data in the related component just like below:

   - Class Component

     ```js
     this.props.location.state; // it is equal to yourData
     ```
   - Function Component

     ```js
     const location = useLocation();
     location.state; // it is equal to yourData
     ```

---

Sometime it will be needed to use `Link` or `NavLink` component instead of using `history.push` function. you can use like below:

```js
<Link
  to={{
    pathname: '/[pathToSomeWhere]',
    state: yourData
  }}
> 
  ...
</Link>
```

**Hint**: the `state` key name should be used in the latest version.

Answer (score 51):

you can use,

`this.props.history.push("/template", { ...response })`
or
`this.props.history.push("/template", { response: response })`

then you can access the parsed data from `/template` component by following code,

`const state = this.props.location.state`

Read more about React [Session History Management](https://javamastermind.com/2020/01/16/react-navigation-manage-session-history/)

Comment: This logic worked for me while history.push with back_url in state 
    this.props.history.push(redirect_url,{ back_url: '/needing_url' });
and getting this at landing page by this.props.location.state.back_url

Answer (score 14):

**If you need to pass URL params**

theres a great post explanation by Tyler McGinnis on his site, [Link to the post](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-url-parameters/)

here are code examples:

1. **on the history.push component:**

   `` this.props.history.push(`/home:${this.state.userID}`) ``
2. **on the router component you define the route:**

   `<Route path='/home:myKey' component={Home} />`
3. **on the Home component:**

```
componentDidMount(){
    const { myKey } = this.props.match.params
    console.log(myKey )
}
```

Comment: I have something like this, but if i refresh the page it completely crashes

Comment: @rabiaasif because the data is not there anymore, you need to persist it or by storing it in local storage

Answer (score 12):

**React TypeScript with Hooks**

From a Class

```
  this.history.push({
      pathname: "/unauthorized",
      state: { message: "Hello" },
    });
```

UnAuthorized Functional Component

```
interface IState {
  message?: string;
}

export default function UnAuthorized() {
  const location = useLocation();
  const message = (location.state as IState).message;

  return (
    <div className="jumbotron">
      <h6>{message}</h6>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: You're better off doing `useLocation<IState>()` so you don't have to assert in the next line

Answer (score 12):

## Pass

```
history.push({pathname:"/yourroute",state: {_id: "0001", name: "AZ"}})
```

## Read

```
import React from 'react';

const YourRoute = props=> {
    const { _id, name } = (props.location && props.location.state) || {};
        //_id and name will contain the passed data
     .
     .
     .

}
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/pass-data-routing-u7foz?from-embed=&file=/src/components/UserForm.js) is a working example

Comment: Is there any way to send URL params as key value pairs? ?key1=value1&key2=value2

Answer (score 6):

I created a custom useQuery hook

```
import { useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

const useQuery = (): URLSearchParams => {
  return new URLSearchParams(useLocation().search)
}

export default useQuery
```

Use it as

```
const query = useQuery();
const id = query.get("id") as string
```

Send it as so

```
history.push({  
 pathname: "/template",
 search: `id=${values.id}`,
});
```

Answer (score 6):

**To use React 16.8 (withHooks) functional component you can use this way**
We sending PhoneNumber to Next Page 
**Login.js**

```
    import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
    const history = useHistory();
        const handleOtpVerify=(phoneNumber)=>
          {
               history.push("/OtpVerifiy",{mobNo:phoneNumber})
          } 

<button onClick={handleOtpVerify}> Submit </button>
```

**OtpVerify.js**

```
    import  useLocation  from 'react-router-dom';
    const [phoneNumber, setphoneNumber] = useState("")
        useEffect(() => {
                setphoneNumber(location.state.mobNo)
            }, [location]);
    return (
    <p>We have sent Verification Code to your</p>
    <h1>{phoneNumber}</h1>
    )
```

**react router dom version 6.2.1** 
useHistory() deprecated changed **useNavigate()**

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

 const navigate = useNavigate()
 
 onClick={() => { navigate('/OtpVerifiy',{mobNo:phoneNumber}) }}
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use `location` to send state to other component, like this

In your **Source Component**

```js
this.props.history.push(pathComponent, sendState);
```

`pathComponent` is target component that will receive the state

In your **Target Component**
you can receive the state like this if your use class component

- Javascript version

```js
constructor(props) {
  this.state = this.props.location.state
}
```

- Typescript version

```js
constructor(props: {}) {
  const receiveState = this.props.location.state as StateType // you must parse into your state interface or type
  this.state = receiveState
}
```

#### Bonus

If you want to reset the received state. Use `history` to replace the location, like this

```js
this.props.history({pathName: currentPath, state: resetState})
```

`currentPath` is the **Target Component** path
`resetState` is new value state whatever you want

Comment: amazingly concise answer.
With React Router v5, you can simply uselocation() hook
```const location = useLocation()
const data = location.state
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not necessary to use withRouter. This works for me:

In your parent page,

```
<BrowserRouter>
   <Switch>
        <Route path="/routeA" render={(props)=> (
          <ComponentA {...props} propDummy={50} />
        )} />

        <Route path="/routeB" render={(props)=> (
          <ComponentB {...props} propWhatever={100} />
          )} /> 
      </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

Then in ComponentA or ComponentB you can access

> this.props.history

object, including the this.props.history.push method.

Comment: I think you didn't need `withRouter` because you wrapped your component with `BrowserRouter`, which works the same.

Comment: Yes and you are passing the `props` down into each component which  include the `history` prop.

Answer (score 2):

To use **React 16.8+(withHooks)** you can use this way

```
import React from 'react';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

export default function SomeFunctionalComponent() {
let history = useHistory(); // should be called inside react component

const handleClickButton = () => {    
"funcionAPICALL"
       .then(response => {
             if (response.status >= 200 && response.status < 300) {
                 history.push('/template');
              });
}

return ( <div> Some component stuff 
    <p>To make API POST request and redirect to "/template" click a button API CALL</p>
    <button onClick={handleClickButton}>API CALL<button>
</div>)
}
```

Source here to read more https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow

Answer (score -10):

Add on info to get query parameters.

```
const queryParams = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
console.log('assuming query param is id', queryParams.get('id');
```

For more info about URLSearchParams check this link 
[URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

Comment: This is not at all relevant to React Router 4.