# passing props on react route change

Tags: reactjs, react-router

*Home.js*

```
class Home extends Component {

    handleClick = () => {
        hashHistory.push('/about')
    }
```

*About.js*

> **Is there a way to send props from Home to About when the route is changed?**

Maybe something similar to sending props to a child component like so:

```
<About name="Sara" />
```

Comment: What's your `react-router` version ?

Comment: "react-router": "^3.0.2",

Comment: check this answer,  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-parameters-with-history-push-in-react-router-v4/45263164#45263164

instead of history.push which is used in the answer, you can do the same with browserHistory as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use history.push not only to change the pathname, but also to add state, a searchquery or a hash.

```
class Home extends Component {

    handleClick = () => {
        history.push({
            pathname: '/about'
            state: { name: "Sara"}
        }
    }
}
```

You could also use the search:

```
class Home extends Component {

    handleClick = () => {
        history.push('/about?name=sara')
    }
}
```

Depending on if you want to have the information in the url.

Then it becomes usable in your route:

```
this.props.location.state
```

or

```
this.props.location.search
```

check [the docs](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/location) for more details.

Comment: By `history.push` u mean `hashHistory.push`? I could only get it to work with `hashHistory.push`

Comment: Now I see you are using v3 of react-router, tbh I dont know much about that. I dont know what exactly what will work/wont work. But if it worked with hashHistory.push that's great :). Also managed to read the state in your new route?

Comment: tbh dont know much about hashHistory either