# How to use constructor value outside constructor?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6

In my component I'm receiving an array object(3 objects only). I want to display them separately and also want to add a `onClick` event to them so that when user clicks any of them I can render different component for each case.
Now the problem is I am accessing the variables inside constructor and rest of the component is outside that scope. What to do in this situation??

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
import MonthToDate from './monthtodate';
import QuarterToDate from './quartertodate';
import YearToDate from './yeartodate';
class Dashboard extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    if(this.props.location && this.props.location.state){
      console.log(this.props.location.state.values.o1)
      var o1=this.props.location.state.values.o1;
      var o2=this.props.location.state.values.o2;
      var o3=this.props.location.state.values.o3;
    }
  }
  callMonth = () => { this.props.history.push({pathname: '/monthtodate'}) };
  callQuarter = () => { this.props.history.push({pathname: '/quartertodate'}) };
  callYear = () => { this.props.history.push({pathname: '/yeartodate'}) };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick:{this.callMonth}>
          <p>MonthToDate: {o1}</p>
        </div>
        <div onClick:{this.callQuarter}>
          <p>QuarterToDate: {o2}</p>
        </div>
        <div onClick:{this.callYear}>
          <p>YearToDate: {o3}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

**NOTE:** Doing `{this.props.location.state.values.o1}` doesn't work inside return as it requires that if condition idk why.
After much Googling I came to know that there is no class variable in react. Instead it has `Context` but it's official docs say **It is an experimental API and it is likely to break in future releases of React**.

The above component is called by Login component ie `login.js` which is as below:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import '../App.css';
import Dashboard from './dashboard';
import {withRouter} from 'react-router';
var axios = require('axios');

class Login extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    //this.state = {isToggleOn: true};
    this.loadDashboard = this.loadDashboard.bind(this);
    this.handleOnSubmit = this.handleOnSubmit.bind(this);
    this.setData = this.setData.bind(this);
    this.state = {values:null}
  }
  setData(data){
    this.setState({values:data});
    //console.log(data);
    this.props.history.push({
      pathname: '/dashboard',
      state: { values: data }
  })
  }
  loadDashboard(token){
    console.log(token);
    axios({
      method:'get',
      url:'http://localhost:3000/api/dashboard',
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
      },
    })
     .then( (response) => {
      // console.log(response.data);
      //  this.props.history.push('/dashboard',this.state.values);
       this.setData(response.data);
     })
     .catch(function (error) {
       console.log("Error in loading Dashboard "+error);
     });
  }

  handleOnSubmit = () => {
     //console.log("submittwed");
     axios({
       method:'post',
       url:'http://localhost:3000/authenticate',
       data: {
         email: 'test@mail.com',
         password: 'apple'
       },
     })
      .then((response) => {
        var token = response.data.auth_token;
      //  console.log(token);
        this.loadDashboard(token);
      })
      .catch(function (error) {
        console.log("Error in login "+error);
      });
   }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
         Username: <input type="email" name="fname" /><br />
         Password: <input type="password" name="lname" /><br />
         <button onClick={this.handleOnSubmit}>LOG IN</button>     
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Login;
```

- How do I pass the variable throughout this class. (NOTE: I don't want to change it in future, just want to display it so no REDUX pls).
- Is there any better approach to tackle this problem?

Comment: You should assign the values from props outside the constructor in componentDidMount or componentWillMount to either state or a class variable or better as @Knut said to use it directly in render with a condition that you have used in constructor

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use local component state as below:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    if(this.props.location && this.props.location.state){
      this.state = {
        o1 : this.props.location.state.values.o1,
        o2 : this.props.location.state.values.o2,
        o3 : this.props.location.state.values.o3
      }
    }
  }
```

Then use it in your render or whatever method you need as below:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div onClick={()=>{this.callMonth()}}>
          <p>MonthToDate: {this.state.o1}</p>
        </div>
        <div onClick={()=>{this.callQuarter()}}>
          <p>QuarterToDate: {this.state.o2}</p>
        </div>
        <div onClick={()=>{this.callYear()}}>
          <p>YearToDate: {this.state.o3}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: It is giving me this error: `Error in loading Dashboard Invariant Violation: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {invoiceAmt, title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons. Check the render method of `Dashboard`.`

Comment: Can you please place a debugger as first statement in if block in the contructor and then hover the cursor over 'this.props.location.state.values.o1' and confirm what you find there.

@mwCoder

Comment: The value is getting passed to the if statement I have checked. When I log the output it displays the object. Previously I had [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46168684/navigate-to-another-route-on-button-click-and-pass-props-to-it?noredirect=1#comment79304763_46168684) issue due to which I had to implement that if block.

Comment: So what do you  mean when you say I want to display the object, of course you cannot straight away render an object inside render.

Comment: how you want to display the objects?

Comment: Your second last comment helped me to understand the issue with object. Now I'm getting this error `Unexpected token in <div div onClick:{this.callMonth}>`. Why doesn't it recognizes `this.callMonth` (I did defined it)??

Comment: Check my updated answer. Notice how I call this method now

Comment: Thanks for your time & answer. So `onClick` cannot directly call a function??

Comment: onClick can directly call a function, and that is what it is doing. I have passed an arrow function to the onClick property ()=>{ //this is function body} <------- inside this I just called your callMonth. So no magic there.

Comment: you can also do this onClick={ this.callMonth.bind(this) }, now here you are directly assigning your callMonth method. Also note in that case you have to bind the context of 'this'.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `this` key word in order to store objects in your `class`.
so you can do something like this for example:

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    if(this.props.location && this.props.location.state){
      console.log(this.props.location.state.values.o1)
      this.o1=this.props.location.state.values.o1;
      this.o2=this.props.location.state.values.o2;
      this.o3=this.props.location.state.values.o3;
    }
  }
```

And acces it the same way:

```
<div onClick:{this.callMonth}>
   <p>MonthToDate: {this.o1}</p>
</div>
```

That being said, i think you should reconsider this approach and maybe access these values directly from props, or create a `state` and store them there.
Either way you should update the objects in the `componentWillReceiveProps` [life cycle method](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#componentwillreceiveprops)

Comment: It gives me this error `Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys {invoiceAmt, title}). If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead or wrap the object using createFragment(object) from the React add-ons.

Check the render method of `Dashboard`.`