# React Router pass id to props

Tags: reactjs, router

I'm trying to pass the id of a page through React Router, but can't wrap my head around how it should be done.

Here is the link:

```js
<Link to={`/forum/${this.props.match.params.forumcatid}/${this.props.match.params.forumsubcatid}/${thread.subject}`} params={{ threadid: thread.id }}>{thread.subject}</Link>
```

And here is the router:

```js
<Route exact={true} path="/forum/:forumcatid/:forumsubcatid/:forumthreadid" component={ForumThread} />
```

I've tried with different approaches, but the id is never passed.

I could just add it as a part of the URL, but I don't want an URL like /forum/324234234/324234/
Instead I want a nice url like so /forum/category/thread/

So how can I pass the id in a hidden way, and keep the names in the url?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-in-react-router-v4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-in-react-router-v4/45263164#45263164)

Comment: any errors in console?

Comment: No errors, but I'm not getting the value passed either :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass your page id through the query parameter.
Like "mynextpage?pageId"

Comment: Thanks man! If I pass it like that, it somehow becomes a state inside location, and then I can simply say: this.props.location.state.threadid