# reactJS history push returns an error

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Hi in my reactJS application I use this

```
this.props.history.push("URL");
```

to redirect to another page or to the same page when I want to reload the page.

But I got this error:

```
Hash history cannot PUSH the same path; a new entry will not be added to the history stack
```

how can I solve this issue?

thanks in advance

Comment: check this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-in-react-router-v4

Comment: Is it warning or an error? Seems like warning to me. If I'm not mistaken, the warning is shown only on dev mode but not in production. Just check if new location is the same as current one `const {history} = this.props; if(history.pathname !== newPath) history.push(newPath);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are looking for this

```
   this.props.history.push({
         pathname: "URL"
      })
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```js
if (history.location.pathname !== somePath) history.push(somePath);
```

Here somePath could be any url.
In react-router-4, pathname can be accessed like

```js
  this.props.history.location.pathname
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace` prop. When replace prop is true, clicking the link will replace the current entry in the history stack instead of adding a new one. To get current pathname use `props.location`.

```
<Link replace={to === location.pathname} to={to}><Button>{to}</Button></Link>
```

You can create higher order function and wrap your `<Link>` in it. So you can use it as

```
<NavLink to="{to}"></NavLink>
```

**[Here is tutorial and example (my blog)](https://filipmolcik.com/react-router-warning-hash-history-cannot-push-the-same-path/)**