# How to pass Props to another component using React-Router Redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redirect, react-router-v4, react-props

I have a pure React app (no external state container) where I use `react-router`. In this app I have a component `<SearchMain />` that contains two children a `<Search />` component, basically a form that contains elements in order to perform a search and a `<DisplayResults />` component that display results in tabular form.

Inside `<Search />` component I have two buttons, one it is used to display data in tabular form, the other to display data in calendar form. The `onClick` events of the two buttons are wired to the `<Search />` parent component through two arrow functions passed as `props`, `updateTableData` and `handleShowCalendar`.

Both functions perform a search and store the result in `this.state.searchResults`. `updateTableData` shows the results in a `<DisplayResults />` component, `handleShowCalendar` wants to show the results in calendar from in another component `<DisplayCalendar />`, linked to the route '/displayCalendar'. 
I would like to use the `<Redirect />` declarative component, instead of using `history.push()`. In the solution below I am able to send the data through the URL's querystring but that's not the solution that I look for, I would like to pass such data the same way props are passed from parent to child components. I looked for information on the web but I couldn't find a solution to my issue. The closest I found is to use

```
<Route
  path='/displayCalendar'
  render={(props) => <DisplayCalendar {...props} searchResults={this.state.searchResults} />}
/>
```

but how can I programmatically change the `<Route />` and pass the state of my component on button click by using `<Redirect />`?

```
export class SearchMain extends React.Component<RouteComponentProps<{}>, State> {

    constructor(props: any)
    {
        super(props);

        this.state = {...};
        ...
    }
        ...
    updateTableData(searchParams: SearchParameters) {
          this.makeRequest(searchParams);
    }

    handleShowCalendar(searchParams: SearchParameters) {
        this.makeRequest(searchParams);
        this.setState({
            ...this.state,
            redirectToCalendar: true
        });
    }

    public render() {
        const { loading, showCalendar, redirectToCalendar, searchResults } = this.state;

        if (redirectToCalendar)
            return (<Redirect to={{
                pathname: '/displayCalendar',
                search: JSON.stringify(this.state.searchResults)
            }} />)

        return (<div>
            <Row>
                <Search search={(searchParams) => 
                  this.updateTableData(searchParams)} showCalendar={(searchParams) => this.handleShowCalendar(searchParams)} />
                {searchResults && <DisplayResults searchResults={searchResults} /> }
                </Row>
           </div>);
    }
```

Comment: Check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-in-react-router-v4/45263164#45263164 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44127739/programmatically-navigate-using-react-router/44128108#44128108

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to pass params with history.push in react-router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-in-react-router-v4)