# Passing state in react-router is not working in react

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-router, react-redux

I have a login page, after successfull login, i want to move to dashboard, where i want to pass the mail id of logged in user to dashboard, i tried `passing` it by `using states` but it is not working

from `login`,

```
if (this.Auth.getToken()) {
            this.props.history.replace({
              pathname: '/dashboard',
              state: { email: this.state.email }
            })
          }
```

to `dashboard`,

```
componentDidMount() {
    if (this.Auth.loggedIn()){
      console.log(this.props.location.state.email)
    }else {
      this.props.history.replace('/login');
    }
  }
```

error,

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined
Dashboard.componentDidMount
src/components/auth/Dashboard.js:15
  12 | }
  13 | componentDidMount() {
  14 |   if (this.Auth.loggedIn()){
> 15 |     console.log(this.props.location.state.email)
  16 |   }else {
  17 |     this.props.history.replace('/login');
  18 |   }
```

full code of login:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
// import * as service from '../../services/service';
import AuthService from '../../services/AuthService'

class Login extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
      email: '',
      password: ''
    }
    this.Auth = new AuthService();
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }
  componentWillMount() {
    if (this.Auth.loggedIn())
      this.props.history.replace('/dashboard');
  }
  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value })
  }
  onSubmit(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var user = {
      email: this.state.email,
      password: this.state.password
    }
    var form1 = document.getElementById("login");
    if (form1.checkValidity() === true) {
      this.Auth.login(user)
        .then(res => {
          if (this.Auth.getToken()) {
            this.props.history.replace({
              pathname: '/dashboard',
              state: { email: this.state.email }
            })
          }
          if (res.status === '404') {
            document.getElementById('error').style.color = 'red';
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = 'Mail Id or Password is Incorrect';
          }
        })
        .catch(err => {
          console.log(err);
        })
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="login">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
                <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Log In</h1>
                <p className="lead text-center">Sign in to your account</p>
                <form id="login" onSubmit={this.onSubmit} noValidate>
                  <span className="lead text-center" id='error'></span>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="email" className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Email Address" name="email" onChange={this.onChange} required />
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">Enter valid email</div>
                  </div>
                  <div className="form-group">
                    <input type="password" className="form-control form-control-lg" placeholder="Password" name="password" minLength="5" onChange={this.onChange} required />
                    <div className="invalid-feedback">Enter atleast 5 characters.</div>
                  </div>
                  <input type="submit" className="btn btn-info btn-block mt-4" />
                </form>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Login;
```

full code of dashboard,

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
// import * as service from '../../services/service';
import AuthService from '../../services/AuthService'

class Dashboard extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this.state = {
    }
    this.Auth = new AuthService();
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.Auth.loggedIn()){
      console.log(this.props.location.state.email)
    }else {
      this.props.history.replace('/login');
    }
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div className="dashboard">
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-md-8 m-auto">
                <h1 className="display-4 text-center">Dashboard</h1>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Route, BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import './App.css';
import Navbar from './components/layout/Navbar'
import Footer from './components/layout/Footer'
import Landing from './components/layout/Landing'
import Login from './components/auth/Login'
import Dashboard from './components/auth/Dashboard'
import Register from './components/auth/Register'
import Logout from './components/auth/Logout'
import Profile from './components/auth/Profile'


class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
        <Router>
          <div className="App">
            <Navbar />
            <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
            <div className="container">
            <Route exact path="/login" component={Login} />
            <Route exact path="/register" component={Register} />
            <Route exact path="/dashboard" component={Dashboard} />
            <Route exact path="/logout" component={Logout} />
            <Route exact path="/profile" component={Profile} />
            </div>
            <Footer />
          </div>
        </Router>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Why don't you just pass it with regular state?

Comment: @Colin im just want to use that state(email), in other components

Comment: Can you put it in your redux store then?

Comment: @Colin i didnot know about redux, can u send me any reference code

Comment: Firstly, you should not use replace but use push, `this.props.history.push('/login');`, Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-in-react-router-v4/45263164#45263164

Comment: Also, when you directly do to the Dashboard component, state will be undefined since you did not supply it, you need to store the email in localStorage if you directly visit the Dashboard page through url

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri ok, i know to store it in local storage, but is there any way to pass when calling `/dashboard`

Comment: Check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-in-react-router-v4/45263164#45263164, also you might consider getting data from localStorage in Dashboard component instead of getting it from state

Comment: i tried with `history.push` also, but it shows same error

Comment: show your main route file as well

Comment: @AshishChoudhary added now

Comment: @FunWorld react and react-router version?

Comment: @AshishChoudhary `"react-router": "^3.2.1"`  `"react": "^16.3.1"`

Comment: @FunWorld update to 4.0.0

Comment: @AshishChoudhary yes man, it's working in react-router 4, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update `react-router` version to `^4.0.0`