# React Routing Redirect onClick

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

Ive been trying to do a simple redirect to another component on button click, but for some reason it doesnt work.I want to redirect to '/dashboard' and display AdminServices from login as follows:

//index.js

```
ReactDOM.render(<BrowserRouter><App /></BrowserRouter>, 
    document.getElementById("root"));
```

//App.js

```
     <Switch>
          <Route path="/" component={Login} />
          <Route path="/dashboard" component={AdminServices} />
        </Switch>
```

//Login.js

```
<Button
onClick={this.login}
>
</Button>

login = () =>{
    <Redirect to="/dashboard" />
  }
```

//AdminServices.js

```
render(){
        return(
            <div>Test</div>
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Instead of using the props.history, a better way is using the useHistory hook like below:

```
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom'

const MyComponent = (props) => {
  const history = useHistory();

  handleOnSubmit = () => {
    history.push(`/dashboard`);
  };
};
```

Comment: is it compatible with React 16.4?

Comment: This is outdated, I think @Mohammad Reza 's answer is better

Answer (score 20):

In react-router-dom v6 you can use `useNavigate()`, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66971821/11320591).

```js
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useNavigate();
navigate('/dashboard');
```

if you're still using previous versions, you can use `useHistory`, as [Tellisense](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63615899/11320591) mentioned.

```js
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';

const navigate = useHistory();
navigate.push('/dashboard');
```

Answer (score 9):

You can route by function by like this

```
  handleOnSubmit = () => {
  this.props.history.push(`/dashboard`);
  };
```

Hope this help

Comment: Tried already but it still wouldnt show my other component. Also Link gives it a weird underline which ill have to deal with later. How can I just use a function to redirect? :)

Comment: I think this should help

Answer (score 1):

Simple, use `NavLink` instead of button

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'

<NavLink to="/dashboard"> Dashboard </NavLink>
```

https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/NavLink

Comment: I specifically want to use button as Im using material design and its inside a card. It'll be ideal to use a button in this case..

Comment: hey @YashankVarshney you can use  `history.push`

https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263164/4089357
 
https://reacttraining.com/react-router/core/api/history

Comment: Sure, I read online that redirecting or linking is a preferred choice than push? Anyways I did try putting NavLink and now it does take me to the right url but for some reason it still shows the same component and not the other one :/

Comment: hmmm, not sure, can you try using `exact` in route i.e. `<Route path="/" exact component={Login} />`

Comment: nvm, I think I just had to use the 'exact' path to get rid of the other component. Works fine now!

Answer (score 1):

With react-router-dom v6 you will need to use `useNavigate` instead of `useHistory`:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export default function MyComponent(){
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  handleOnClick = () => {
    navigate("/dashboard");
  };
};
```

Answer (score 0):

`<Switch>` component render only the first route that matches. You just need to swap your `<Route>` components in `<Switch>` case and use `@Adnan shah` answer to make redirect function.

P.S
[react router auth example](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/auth-workflow)

Comment: So should I just get rid of the <Switch> at all? You were right about it routing only to the first component.. Now that Im trying to go from '/dashbaord' to '/addservice', it doesnt work :/ Do I remove it completely?

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me once I had missed importing the component to the route.js file.

You need to reference/import files from the component to the routefile.

Answer (score 0):

Use an a tag

```
<a href="/" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this might help

```
import { useHistory } from "react-router-dom";
const history = useHistory();
<Button
onClick={this.login}
>
</Button>

login = () =>{
     history.push("/about");
  }
```