# React js: React router not redirecting when button is being clicked

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, router

I have been trying to solve this problem for couple days and still couldnt get it to work. How does redirecting not work here? I keep getting the "TypeError: history is undefined". Also when the button is being clicked, it stays at the same url. What am I doing wrong?

```
import React from 'react';
import Nav from './Nav';
import About from './About';
import Service from './Service';
import Home from './Home';
import {
    BrowserRouter as Router,
    Switch,
    Route,
    useHistory,
} from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
    const history = useHistory();
    function handleSub() {
        // console.log('clicked');
        history.push('/about');
    }
    return (
        <div className='App'>
            <button onClick={handleSub}>submit</button>
            <Router>
                <Nav />
                <Switch>
                    <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                    <Route path='/service' component={Service} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        </div>
    );
}

export default App;
```

Edit: implemented the answers and still having trouble.
Suggestion 1: place the button inside the router: url switches for links or button is clicked but pages for the links not when the button is clicked.

```
function App() {
const history = useHistory();
function handleSub() {
    // console.log('clicked');
    history.push(`/about`);
}
return (
    <Router>
        <div className='App'>
            <Nav />
            <button onClick={handleSub}>submit</button>
            <Switch>
                <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
                <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                <Route path='/service' component={Service} />
            </Switch>
        </div>
    </Router>
);
```

}

Suggestion number two: url swtich for all the links and button but the page never loads.

```
function App() {
    const history = useHistory();
    function handleSub() {
        // console.log('clicked');
        history.push(`/about`);
    }
    return (
        <Router>
            <div className='App'>
                <Nav />
                <Switch>
                    <button onClick={handleSub}>submit</button>
                    <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
                    <Route path='/about' component={About} />
                    <Route path='/service' component={Service} />
                </Switch>
            </div>
        </Router>
    );
}
```

Comment: You're trying to use history outside the context of your `Router`. The router must be moved to a higher level of the component tree, or the `useHistory` to a lower one.

Comment: I believe your onClick may also need to be updated to `onClick={() => handleSub()}`

Comment: @CWSites the OP's handler syntax is fine, adding another anonymous function does nothing.

Comment: @lawrence-witt gotcha - in the past I've had issues where if not used this way it calls it on each render. Perhaps it's my lack of understanding on how this works.

Comment: @CWSites that would be true if they had put `onClick={handleSub()}` which is indeed a common error.

Comment: That makes sense, thanks

Comment: @lawrence-witt ok so I moved the button inside the router and still didnt work? ` return ( <div className='App'> <Router> <button onClick={handleSub}>submit</button> <Nav /> <Switch> <Route path='/' exact component={Home} /> <Route path='/about' component={About} /> <Route path='/service' component={Service} /> </Switch> </Router> </div> );`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply because you are calling `useHistory` hook outside of `React Router Switch` Component, meaning you should use this hook in all `Switch` child components, otherwise the history object is undefined. The best way for my opinion is to move the button to the `Home` Component, then surly it will work.

I hope this answer helped you.

Comment: This solved the problem! I moved the button to different component and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

If you use it like this

```
<Button color='primary' onClick={handleSub('/about')}>Submit</Button>
```

and in your method do it like this.

```
    const handleSub = (path) => async (e) => {
    history.push(path)}
```

I hope it will solve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the placement of the button which is the issue, but as originally mentioned, the placement of `useHistory`. The history hook is expecting context provided by the `Router` component - if you are familiar with `useContext`, it's exactly the same here. You must be calling `useHistory` inside a component which is a child of `Router`.

I'll mock an `index.js` file to demonstrate:

```
// index.js

import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';
import App from './App';

const rootHtml = (
  <Router>
    <App />
  </Router>
);


ReactDOM.render(rootHtml, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Remove the original router in the `App` component. Now this top level router has the `App` component in scope and can provide it with history context for `useHistory` to use.