# Unable to redirect a component with react-router-dom

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to redirect to ProductId Component when there is a click on div with a className= "card" `<div className="card" onClick={()=>CallComponent(_id)}>`

The function CallComponent is:

```
CallComponent = (_id) => {
   console.log("Clicked");
   <Link to="/productnew">
   </Link>;
   <Route path="/productnew" component={ProductId}></Route>
};
```

When there is a click on card "Clicked" is seen in the console but the component is not routed

Comment: So basically you have to navigate to `/productnew` when you click the div correct?

Comment: @GiovanniEsposito Yes

Comment: I think this will help [React routing onClick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51393153/react-routing-redirect-onclick)

Comment: @DanDemon are you using React with or without hooks?

Answer (score 1):

To programmatically navigate to `/productnew` route you could use `Redirect` in combination with a state variable. Something like:

```
import { Redirect } from "react-router-dom";

...

state = { redirect: null };

CallComponent = (_id) => {
   console.log("Clicked");
   this.setState({ redirect: "/productnew" });
};


render() {
  if (this.state.redirect) {
    return <Redirect to={this.state.redirect} />
  }
  return(
  // Your Code goes here
  )
}
```

[This](https://dev.to/projectescape/programmatic-navigation-in-react-3p1l) is an intersting article if you want read more about this topic.