# How to pass props to routes using redirect

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am working on a reactjs project where i have to pass props form component A to Component B now , Component A has the following code inside render function:

```html
{this.state.showComponentedit ?
<div>
<Redirect to={'/editB'} editdata={this.state.feedData} />: null
</div>
}
```

I am getting the current data passed by B in A component using following code:

```html
// inside a random function which will be invoked on button press
console.log("Props from B", this.props.edidata);
```

The edidata is null in Component A. how can i get the value when i am invoking the rooute "editB" and use that value in component B. Thank you

Comment: Is your component `A` is the `HOC` of component `B`?

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [How to pass params with history.push in react-router v4?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-in-react-router-v4/45263164#45263164)

Answer (score 1):

You can also pass an object to 'to' prop of Redirect like this:

```
<Redirect to={{
  pathname='/editB'
  state={
    editdata: this.state.feedData
  }
}}/>
```

After that in editB component you can get the data from:

> this.props.location.state

I hope this approach will solve your problem.

Comment: may i know more about location because i am finding an error when i try to access using this.props.location.state.editdata . my js script is saying location is undefined.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do this:

```
<Redirect
  to={{
    pathname: "/login",
    search: "?utm=your+face",
    state: { referrer: currentLocation }
  }}
/>
```

The state object can be accessed via this.props.location.state in the B component.

More details: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Redirect/to-object

Answer (score 0):

First you have to make the data from B accessible to A

You can do that by lifting the data to the parent component and then passing that data to A using `Route`

```
 <Route
   exact={true}
   path="/mycomponent"
   render={props => <EditComponent editData={this.state.feedData} />}
 />
```