# React router not working as expected when pass state to history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-v4

I have some form where i get user reservation details and then on submit i redirect user to other page by history.push('/somepath') but when i pass props by history.push({ pathname: '', state:{} }) then my url changes but my component is not rendered, this is the first time im facing this problem and now my head hurts, I dont know where the problem is or why this is happening. I have another form which works fine when i use history.push({ pathname: '', state:{} }) there.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { BrowserRouter, Switch, Route, Redirect } from 'react-router-dom';
import Navbar from './components/Navbar/Navbar';
import Home from './pages/Home/Home';
import Login from './pages/Login/Login';
import Signup from './pages/Signup/Signup';
import Vehicles from './pages/Vehicles/Vehicles';
import About from './pages/About/About';
import VehiclesListView from './pages/Vehicles/VehiclesListView';
import Checkout from './pages/Checkout/Checkout';

function App({ user }) {
    const [ isAuth, setAuth ] = React.useState(false);

    return (
        <BrowserRouter basename="/">
            <Navbar isAuth={isAuth} setAuth={(v) => setAuth(v)} />
            <Switch>
                <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
                <Route path="/vehicles" component={Vehicles} />
                <Route exact path="/reserve/checkout" component={Checkout} />
                <Route exact path="/reserve" component={VehiclesListView} />
                <Route path="/about" component={About} />

                {!user && (
                    <Switch>
                        <Route path="/login" render={() => <Login setAuth={(v) => setAuth(v)} />} />
                        <Route path="/signup" component={Signup} />
                    </Switch>
                )}
                <Redirect to="/" />
            </Switch>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
}

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    user: state.user.currentUser
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(App);
```

Form.js

```
const submit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    history.push({
        pathname: `/reserve?type=${type}&zipcode=${pickup.zip}`,
        state: {
            type,
            pickup,
            dropOff,
            pickupTime,
            dropTime
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Just wondering where is form.js is i mean in which parent component ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this should work for you.

```
history.push(`/reserve?type=${type}&zipcode=${pickup.zip}`, 
      state: {
            type,
            pickup,
            dropOff,
            pickupTime,
            dropTime
     }
);
```

or alternatively like this,

```
history.push({
  pathname: '/reserve',
  search: '?type=${type}&zipcode=${pickup.zip}',
  state: { detail: response.data }
})
```

Comment: yeah it worked, thank you very much but can you explain why this worked?

Comment: You were passing object to push. While push accepts two parameters first as path which is string and second as object that is state.

Comment: but that syntax i mentioned in the question is working fine in my other onClick handler

Comment: This syntax is not right - you need to remove `state: `

Comment: Wrong syntax !. => https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263164/11302100