# how to use data that are sent by this.props.history?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-router-dom

When I want to go from a route to another with *this.props.history.push("/")*, also I want to send some additional data, for example: **this.props.history.push('/postDetail', {data: item})**. But I do not know how where to define this data in the class where we went.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You can se it here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-link-redirect-in-react-router-v4

Answer (score 0):

You can send a prop called state that comes from the router:

```
this.props.history.push({
 pathname: '/postDetail',
 state: { data: item }
});
```

So now your component attached with that route will have the location prop available, inside the location object lies the state that you have passed.
More info here: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/history