# How to navigate page and pass through props from within a function (React)

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have used Link and react Router dom to navigate and pass props.

Here is my function

```
 pageRelocator(mssg) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem("mssg");
    if (mssg.length < 35) {
      window.location.href = "http://localhost:3000/completed-assessment";
    } else if (mssg.length > 35) {
      window.localStorage.setItem("mssg", mssg);
      window.location.href = `http://localhost:3000/user-questions`;
    }
  }
```

I would like to conditionally navigate to a page and pass the prop mssg through.

I am fully aware how to do this through redirect/ Link etc but my understanding is that this is done within the jsx how would I navigate AND pass props through to a page doing it in this manner.

Comment: its help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-link-redirect-in-react-router-v4

Answer (score 2):

Something simple like this?

```
const pushPayload = mssg.length > 35 ? {
  pathname: '/user-questions',
  state: { mssg },
} : {
  pathname: '/completed-assessment'
};

history.push(pushPayload);
```

On `'/user-questions'` route access the passed state (using guards if appropriate) off the `history` prop/object:

```
history.location.state.mssg
```

Comment: Thanks I will give this a go later