# how to pass value from one component to another in react js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, properties

I have one component in which I have one button and I am calling one node js service on that. I am getting a response back from that service and I want to pass that response on next component to display a data there. Below is my component which is doing a node js call.

```
import { FormGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import axios from "axios";


export default class Abc extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        axios.get(url)
            .then(res => {
                this.setState({
                    data: res.data// I need this variable to pass to next component Pqr where I can use it for display purpose.
                })
                this.props.history.push("/Pqr",{ response:res.data});
            })
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <form >
                <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={this.handleClick} style={{ whitespace: 'nowrap' }} >
                    Launch
                    </button>
            </form>
        )

    }
}


My Pqr component code is as below.

import React from "react";

export default class ModelLaunch extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);

        this.state = {
        }
    }
    render() {
        const state = this.props.location.state
        return (
        <h1>This page will display model Inputs : {state} </h1>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-link-redirect-in-react-router-v4

Comment: there is only one component here. you need a child component to pass this data to if you're just using state declared in a component.

Comment: @JoeLloyd I have added my Pqr component code as well. I am still not able to access the data.

Comment: But they have no relationship. you cant send data that you declare in a component if the receiver is not a child.
If you need to do this you should implement the contextHook or better still Redux

Comment: @JoeLloyd how to use hooks, I am new in react and working on one poc, So not aware all the things in react. Could you please help.

Comment: its too big to go into in a comment. go read the hooks docs and read about react state management. You need to understand these 2 fundamentals, there is no easy fix for this issue outside of proper state management.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved above problem with other way. Instead of calling a node js service on Abc component I am just redirecting it to new coponent and in new component's componentDidMount() method I am calling a node js service and storind a data in props. In this way I have my data on new copmonent. Below is my updated code in Abc component now.

```js
import { FormGroup } from "react-bootstrap";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
import axios from "axios";


export default class Abc extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            data: {}
        }
        this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this);
    }

    handleClick = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
                this.props.history.push("/Pqr");
            })
    };

    render() {

        return (
            <form >
                <button className="btn btn-info btn-sm" onClick={this.handleClick} style={{ whitespace: 'nowrap' }} >
                    Launch
                    </button>
            </form>
        )

    }
```

And in pqr coponent's code as below

```js
import React from "react";
import axios from "axios";

export default class Pqr extends React.Component{
 constructor(props)
 {
  super(props);
  this.state = { 
   data :[]
  }
 }

 componentDidMount(){

        axios.get(url).then((res) => {
            console.log("res****",res.data)
            this.setState({
                data:res.data
            })
        }).catch((err) =>{
            console.log("err", err)
        })
    }
 render()
 {
  return(
  <h1>This page will display data</h1>
  )
 }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I see you're changing a route (using react-router?).

Remember that `this.setState` is async and specific for your component, when you call `this.props.history.push('/Pqr')`, maybe the `this.state.data` is not updated yet.

To share this data through different `routes` in the same react project, I actually know that you can:

- Store it on `window.localStorage` and then get on the next route [here have a tutorial](https://www.robinwieruch.de/local-storage-react)
- Use [react contexts to share data between components](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html#when-to-use-context) (if you're not reloading the page)
- Send data through routes with react-router, [as explained here](https://tylermcginnis.com/react-router-pass-props-to-components/)

If its not the case, and you just want to pass the property down or above the hierarchy tree, in addition to the comments above, maybe it can help:

As you probably know, react projects are composed of components that are put all together to work in a specific way. In the example below, there are two components (father and child)

```
import React from 'react';

// We can say that this component is "below" Father
function Child(props) {
  return (
    <button>
      Hey, I'm a button!
    </button>
  );
}

// We can say that this component is "above" Child
function Father(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <Child />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I couldn't find in the provided code/question, one `child` component, maybe you forgot to write it?

If the response is "yes", I'll create a fictional component called... `FictionalComponent` (I'm a Genius!), and pass the data on state as a property named... `data`.

In order to pass this property, if its the case, you just need to update your render method to look like this:

```
  render() {
    return (
      <form >
        <button 
          className="btn btn-info btn-sm" 
          onClick={this.handleClick} 
          style={{ whitespace: 'nowrap' }} 
        >
          Launch
          <FictionalComponent data={this.state.data} />
        </button>
      </form>
    )
  }
```

This way, when `this.state.data` changes, the `FictionalComponent` will be re-rendered with the new `data` value.

But, maybe you want the reverse operation and you need to pass the `this.state.data` to the component above your `Abc`, listed there when the button is pressed.

To achieve it you need to have a "Father" component to your `Abc`, the "Father" component must provide an `onDataChanged` callback in order to capture the event. This callback will receive the `data` and handle it.

In this case, I'll create another component to be the component **above** your `Abc`. I'll name it... `AboveAbcComponent`, perfect!

```
...

class AboveAbcComponent extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = {
      dataFromChild: null
    };

    this.onDataChanged = this.onDataChanged.bind(this);
  }

  onDataChanged(dataReceived) {
    console.log("Yey! It works!");
    this.setState({ dataFromChild: dataReceived });
  }

  render() {// Just the passed props changes here
    ...
      <Abc 
        onDataChanged={this.onDataChanged}
      />
    ...
  }
}

export default class Abc extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) { ... } // No changes here

  handleClick = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    axios.get(url)
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res.data
        });

        this.props.onDataChanged(res.data);

        this.props.history.push("/Pqr"); // I really didn't understand Why this push is here... but ok
      })
  };

  render() { ... } // No changes here
}
```

Hope it helps, have fun!

Comment: I gone through above links but still unclear on how to implement it in my code.