# React - redirect and render component with props with react router

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, browser-history

I have a `functional component` Profile, I only want users to access it if they are authenticated, if not, they should be redirected.

```
import React from 'react';
import {useAuth0} from '@auth0/auth0-react';

export const Profile = ({history}) => {
  const {user, isAuthenticated} = useAuth0();

  if (!isAuthenticated) history.push('/');
  const {email, picture} = user;

  return (
    <div>
      <h4>Profile</h4>
      <p>{email}</p>
      <p>{picture}</p>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here I get an error if I try to access the /profile directly.

```
`TypeError: Cannot destructure property 'email' of 'user' as it is` undefined.
```

What I would like to do is the following:

- render the `Home` component if the user is not authenticated and pass a props boolean.
- redirect the app to `'/'`

I am trying to combine `history.push('/')` and return `<Home message={true}/>` but this doesn't work since the props is not being passed.

Is there a way to combine both? Or am I missing some extra steps?

Answer (score 0):

The code after `history.push('/')` is causing error as the `isauthenticated` is false then user object does not contain those fields and hence the error!

```
import React from 'react';
import {useAuth0} from '@auth0/auth0-react';

export const Profile = ({history}) => {
  const {user, isAuthenticated} = useAuth0();

  if(!isAuthenticated) {
     history.push('/');
     return
  }

  else{ 
    const {email, picture} = user;

    return (
      <div>
        <h4>Profile</h4>
        <p>{email}</p>
        <p>{picture}</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

This should work!!

Comment: Function returns only after either return is encountered or end of block of the function!

Comment: Thanks! Is it possible to send props to another component at the same time as I redirect the user to '/'?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-link-redirect-in-react-router-v4

Comment: Accept the answer if it helped you , to mark the question answered! If there's any more doubt you are free to ask !