# Passing the variable from Route path to another Route path?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

index.js

```
function start(){
  ReactDOM.render(
    <Router history={hist}>
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/making" component={MakingPage} />
        <Route path="/dashboard" render={() => <DashboardPage name={'Tom'}/>}/>
      </Switch>
    </Router>,
    document.getElementById("root")
  );
}
```

I can give the param `name` like this.

DashboardPage.js

```
class DashboardPage extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render(){
    console.log(this.props.name)// Tom comes here!
  } 
}
```

I could pass the param from `index.js` to  `DashboardPage.js`

Now I have the variable `myParam=1` in `MakingPage`

then I want to move to `dashboard` page and give the `myParam=1` parameter.

Is it possible? or bad idea?

```
export default function MakingPage(props) {
  function giveParam(){
     let mParam = 1;
     //I want to move /dashboard page and give the `myParam=1` to `dashboardPage` like `name={'Tom')`  
  }
  return (

  );
}
```

Comment: You can do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-link-redirect-in-react-router-v4)

Comment: Thank you . I can solve this.