# How to access the data passed through "this.props.history.push(...)"

Tags: reactjs

Constructor code which contains the data

```
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        Data: [
            {
                "name": 'red'
            },
            {
                "name": 'green'
            },
            {
                "name": 'red'
            },
            {   
               "name": 'brown'
            },
            {
                "name": 'yellow'
            },
            {
                "name": 'brown'
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

The code for my button where I map the data

```
{this.state.Data.map((color) => (
                        <>
                        <div className="ViewDetailsBtn"><Button onClick={this.clickMe.bind(this, color.name)} className="ViewDetailsBtnLink">View Details</Button></div></>
                        
                    ))}
```

onClick function Code

```
clickMe = (details) => {
    console.log(details);
    this.props.history.push({
        pathname: "/ViewDetails", 
        state: {detail: details}
    });
}
```

Here it displays the color name on my console properly and it redirects me to ViewDetails but how do I display the color name on the ViewDetails page?

ViewDetails page code

```
    import React from 'react'
    const App = (props) => {
    console.log(props);
    //const data = props.location.state.detail;
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>Details:-</h1>
            {/* <h1>{data}</h1> */}
        </div>
    )
   }

   export default App
```

Comment: you can do props.location.state.data

Comment: So should I type in "const data = props.location.state.data"? and should I display it by "<h1>{data}</h1>"? I'm pretty new to this.

Comment: it depends on what you have in `data` . if your data is a string then you can do what you said above .

Comment: Yea, it's a string. But it's not working :/. Getting an error "TypeError: Cannot read property 'data' of undefined". I've updated the code in the question for ViewDetails

Comment: Is your `ViewDetails` component rendered via `Route` ? . Also add a `console.log(props)` and check whether you are able to see `location` in it .

Comment: The way you are adding state in `props.history.push` is wrong . Please refer this - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-link-redirect-in-react-router-v4

Comment: How is `ViewDetails` rendered? What routing/navigation package are you using? More context is necessary. Can you provide us a [Minimal, ***Complete***, and ***Reproducible*** Code Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: It's rendered through Route. I added a console.log(props) in my ViewDetails page. It displays the location in the console too. It says "hash: ""
key: "6ekowq"
pathname: "/ViewDetails"
search: """
But the color name can't be seen.

I've edited the question again with more context on what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: The main problem is, I can't add a state to the props. Pathname is working, but state isn't..

Comment: From your limited code snippet I see no reason why route state *wouldn't* be accessible. Can you create a *running* codesandbox that reproduces this issue that we can live inspect and debug in?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/muddy-forest-0n5ky?file=/src/index.js
I'm not sure why It's not displaying anything, but here is the full code. Would really appreciate it if you could help me in displaying the color onClick in ViewDetails page.

Answer (score 1):

your ViewDetails component should accept a parameter:
`const ViewDetails = (props) => {}`
then you should be able to access that data through that parameter

Comment: Could you also tell how to acces the data through the parameter? How should I define the parameter?