# How to pass props with history.push

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props

I have 2 pages: betslip.jsx and receipt.jsx.

When a button is clicked in betslip.jsx I redirect the user to receipts.jsx, giving value for 2 props with the following code:

```
history.push({
    state: { authorized:true, total:10},
    pathname: '/receipt'
})
```

From my reading, this SHOULD work but the prop values are never received in receipts as receipts look like this:

```
export default function Receipt({authorized, total}) {

    console.log('authorized: ', authorized);
    console.log('total: ', total);

    if(!authorized){
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Authorized is still false, the total is still 0 (their initial values).

Am I missing something obvious here? Pls advice

Comment: Can you check the comment here, see if this helps https://stackoverflow.com/a/45263164/10293708

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to do this inside of the page you want to direct to:

```
const location = useLocation();
if(location.state){
    authorized = location.state.authorized;
    total = location.state.total;
} else{
    if(!authorized){
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this inside your component

```
const location = useLocation();
const {authorized, total} = location.state;
```

**Receipt** component

```
export default function Receipt(props) {
    const location = useLocation();

    const {authorized, total} = location.state;
    console.log('authorized: ', authorized);
    console.log('total: ', total);

    if(!authorized){
        return <Redirect to="/" />;
    }
    return (
        <div>
            <h1>hello</h1>
        </div>
    )
 }
```