# this.props.history.push has undefined state

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to send some data from my `SignInForm` class to another component through `this.history.push` using the state parameter.

However, when I look over in the `AdminPage` class, the props for state are `undefined`.

How can I correctly send data from one class to another using `history.push`?

*SignInForm.js*

```
  .then(response =>{
  const my_user = this.state.user;

  if(response.status === 200){
      this.setState({user : response.data})
    }
      if(this.state.user.roles[0].roleCode === 'ADMIN'){
        this.props.history.location.pathname = "/"; 
        
        // user :{"id":1,"name":"name ","email":"name@gmail.com","roles":[{"id":1,"roleCode":"ADMIN","roleDescription":"restaurant administrattor","authority":"ADMIN"}]}
        console.log("user :" + JSON.stringify(my_user));
        this.props.history.push({pathname: "adminPage", state : { user : my_user}});
      }
      else if(this.state.user.roles[0].roleCode === 'USER'){
        this.props.history.location.pathname = "/";
        this.props.history.push({pathname: "customerPage",state :{ user : my_user}});
      }

  })
  .catch(error => this.setState({error : true,message : "cannot decrypt user info"}))


  })
  .catch(error => this.setState({error : true,message : "cannot decrypt user info"}))
```

*AdminPage.js*

```
constructor(props){ 
    super(props)
    this.state = {
        user : this.props.history.location.state.user
    }
    console.log(this.state.user);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    this.props.history.push({pathname: "adminPage", state : { user : my_user}});
```

change into

```
 this.props.history.push("/adminPage", { state: user});
```

[Refrence 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44121069/how-to-pass-params-with-history-push-link-redirect-in-react-router-v4)
[Refrence 2](https://codesource.io/how-to-use-this-props-history-push-on-your-react-project/)